# How do you use a TextPainter to draw text?

Tags: dart, flutter

The [documentation for CustomPainter's paint method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CustomPainter/paint.html) says, "To paint text on a `Canvas`, use a `TextPainter`". So within my `MyCustomPainter`'s paint method I have the following:

```
TextSpan span = new TextSpan(text: 'Yrfc');
TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left);
tp.layout();
tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(5.0, 5.0));
```

I've tried a variety of offsets `(Offset.zero, Offset.infinite, new Offset(10.0, 10.0)` but I never am able to see the text painted on the screen.

Comment: One thing for people to be aware of before copying the code above is that it is relatively expensive to recreate the TextPainter each time (specifically, the call to `layout` is expensive). Where possible, you want to keep the TextPainter around and reuse it, only calling `layout` on it when the arguments to that method change.

Comment: @IanHickson whenever I try to reuse a textpainer, I get "TextPainter.paint called when text geometry was not yet calculated". I can create a new textpainter every time, and it works, but seem unable to reuse a textpainter. Are there any examples out there you are aware of which show this ? (actually I think it needs a new painter every time text changes, so not quite sure how often one would be able to reuse the painter ?)

Comment: You have to make sure to call "layout" on the text painter after setting any of its properties, to recompute the geometry.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the answer as I was typing up this question but I've been wrestling with it for a while now, so posting in case it helps anyone else.

What solved it was changing the TextSpan line to:

`TextSpan span = new TextSpan(style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]), text: 'Yrfc');`

Apparently it was either drawing the text invisibly or as white (background) color since I hadn't made my color choice explicit.

Comment: The default text color is indeed white.

Answer (score 48):

[image]

To paint in Flutter you use the [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget. The `CustomPaint` widget takes a [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) object as a parameter. In that class you have to override the `paint` method, which gives you a canvas that you can paint on. Here is the code to draw the text in the image above.

```dart
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  const textStyle = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 30,
  );
  const textSpan = TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello, world.',
    style: textStyle,
  );
  final textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: textSpan,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  );
  textPainter.layout(
    minWidth: 0,
    maxWidth: size.width,
  );
  final xCenter = (size.width - textPainter.width) / 2;
  final yCenter = (size.height - textPainter.height) / 2;
  final offset = Offset(xCenter, yCenter);
  textPainter.paint(canvas, offset);
}
```

#### Notes:

- If you are using a white background, be sure to set the text color to some other color besides white, which is the default.
- Flutter makes an effort to not assume a text direction, so you need to set it explicitly. The abbreviation `ltr` stands for left-to-right, which languages like English use. The other option is `rtl` (right-to-left), which languages like Arabic and Hebrew use. This helps to reduce bugs when the code is used in language contexts that developers were not thinking about.

#### Context

Here is the **main.dart** code so that you can see it in context.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: HomeWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CustomPaint( //                       <-- CustomPaint widget
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: MyPainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter { //         <-- CustomPainter class
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //                                             <-- Insert your painting code here.
  }
  
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

#### See also

See [this article](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10) for my fuller answer.

Comment: Thanks. Everything worked perfectly. The only improvement would be to figure out an automatic way of centering the text instead of using `Offset(50, 100)` - left/top padding.

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki, After you call `textPainter.layout` you will have access to `textPainter.width` and `textPainter.width`. I've updated the answer to center the text.

Answer (score 24):

In the TextPainter constructor, need also specify the **TextDirection** parameter, otherwise you'll receive an exception:

```
TextSpan span = new TextSpan(style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]), text: name);
TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
tp.layout();
tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(5.0, 5.0));
```