# Meaning of Paragraph in Flutter classes

Tags: text, flutter

There are several classes and methods in Flutter that have "Paragraph" in the name. Examples:

- [Paragraph](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paragraph-class.html)
- [ParagraphBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ParagraphBuilder-class.html)
- [RenderParagraph](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderParagraph-class.html)
- [ParagraphStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ParagraphStyle-class.html)
- [Canvas.drawParagraph](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawParagraph.html)

What is the meaning of paragraph here? Usually I think of a paragraph of text as a few of sentences with no new line characters. Can a Flutter paragraph contain multiple new lines?

The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paragraph-class.html) isn't clear:

> **Paragraph class**
>
> A paragraph of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Flutter Paragraph can contain more that one newline character. This can be demonstrated by using the following text string in a ParagraphBuilder or a TextPainter, which creates a single Paragraph in the Flutter sense of the word.

```
final text = 'My text line.\nThis line is longer than the last.\nAnother line.';
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896124/3681880) and [here](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10).

#### See also

- [What is the meaning Flutter's width metrics for the Paragraph class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083632/what-is-the-meaning-flutters-width-metrics-for-the-paragraph-class/57083633#57083633)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Expanded instead, and when you want to create new paragraph, add these lines of codes:

```
final text = "Paragraph one \n\n Paragraph two \n\n Paragraph three";
```