# how to draw number '6' using path with animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Need to draw perfect 6 shape (ref ima) using dart.

Like this...
[image]

tried below code not giving perfect 6

```
 
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double ht = size.height;
    double wt = size.width;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(wt / 2 + 5, 5);

    path.cubicTo(wt / 2 + 10, 5, wt / 6, ht / 2, wt / 2, ht - 10);

    path.cubicTo(wt / 2, ht - 10, wt, ht / 1.8, wt / 2 - 25, ht / 2);

    canvas.drawPath(path, _paint);
  }
```

Comment: What is a “perfect 6”?

Comment: like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Unicode_0x0036.svg/800px-Unicode_0x0036.svg.png

Comment: Could you not use a font to just put a 6 there without drawing it yourself? Like this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371449/how-do-you-use-a-textpainter-to-draw-text

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks able to draw as I need. facing issue with animation part

Comment: Where does it mention animation in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can able to draw as below,

```
 path.moveTo(wt / 1.4, 40);
    path.cubicTo(wt / 2 + 10, 20, wt / 4, ht / 4, wt / 2.9, ht / 1.4);

    path.addArc(
        Rect.fromCenter(
            center: Offset(wt / 2 + 8, ht / 1.5),
            width: wt / 2.4,
            height: wt / 2.3),
        math.pi,
        (2 * math.pi));

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```